# Proving using squeeze principle

Tags: calculus, integration, discrete-mathematics, recreational-mathematics, contest-math

[image: please help me solve this problem]

This problem sounds very confusing. Please help me solve this problem.

Comment: Do you know what the result of 2.5.14 is?

Comment: The hint given is very clear. You must have studied a formula for $\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\sin^{n}(x)\,dx$ probably "the result of 2.5.14". Just use the same formula in the inequality given in the hint and you will be able to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle #1 \right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace #1 \right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack #1 \right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil #1 \right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\down}{\downarrow}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\equalby}[1]{{#1 \atop {= \atop \vphantom{\huge A}}}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left( #1 \right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
$\ds{{\cal I}_{n} \equiv \pars{2 \over 1}^{2}\pars{4 \over 3}^{2}
     \pars{6 \over 5}^{2}\ldots \pars{2n \over 2n - 1}^{2}{1 \over 2n + 1}\,,\qquad
     \lim_{n \to \infty}{\cal I}_{n}:\ {\large ?}}$

> \begin{align}
> \ln\pars{{\cal I}_{n}} + \ln\pars{2n + 1}&=
> \sum_{k = 0}^{n - 1}\ln\pars{\bracks{2k + 2\over 2k + 1}^{2}}
> =2\sum_{k = 0}^{n - 1}\ln\pars{2k + 2 \over 2k + 1}
> =2\sum_{k = 0}^{n - 1}\int_{0}^{1}{\dd x \over x + 2k + 1}
> \\[3mm]&=\int_{0}^{1}\dd x\sum_{k = 0}^{n - 1}{1 \over k + \pars{1 + x}/2}
> =\int_{0}^{1}\bracks{\Psi\pars{{1 + x \over 2} + n} - \Psi\pars{x + 1 \over 2}}\dd x
> \end{align}
>   where $\ds{\Psi\pars{z} = \dd\ln\pars{\Gamma\pars{z}}/\dd z}$. $\Gamma$ and $\Psi$ are the Gamma and Digamma
>   [functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygamma_function), respectively.

Then
\begin{align}
\ln\pars{{\cal I}_{n}}&=-\ln\pars{2n + 1}
\left.+2\ln\pars{\Gamma\pars{\bracks{x + 2n + 1}/2}
                 \over \Gamma\pars{\bracks{x + 1}/2}}\right\vert_{0}^{1}
\\[3mm]&=-\ln\pars{2n + 1}
+ 2\ln\pars{{\Gamma\pars{n + 1} \over \Gamma\pars{1}}\,
           {\Gamma\pars{1/2} \over \Gamma\pars{n + 1/2}}}
\end{align}

> Since $\Gamma\pars{1/2} = \root{\pi}$ and $\Gamma\pars{1} = 1$:
>   \begin{align}
> \ln\pars{{\cal I}_{n}}&=-\ln\pars{n + \half}
> +2\ln\pars{\Gamma\pars{n + 1} \over \Gamma\pars{n + 1/2}} + \ln\pars{\pi \over 2}
> \end{align}

However, when $n \gg 1$:
\begin{align}
&{\Gamma\pars{n + 1} \over \Gamma\pars{n + 1/2}}
={\root{2\pi}\pars{n + 1}^{n + 3/2}\expo{-n - 1}
  \over \root{2\pi}\pars{n + 1/2}^{n + 1}\expo{-n - 1/2}}
=n^{1/2}\,{\pars{1 + 1/n}^{n + 3/2} \over \pars{1 + 1/2n}^{n + 1}}\,\expo{-1/2}
\sim n^{1/2}\,{\expo{1} \over \expo{1/2}}\,\expo{-1/2} \\[3mm]&= n^{1/2}
\end{align}

> Then
>   $$
> \ln\pars{{\cal I}_{n}}\sim-\ln\pars{n + \half} + 2\ln\pars{n^{1/2}}
> + \ln\pars{\pi \over 2}
> =-\ln\pars{1 + {1 \over 2n}} + \ln\pars{\pi \over 2}\,,\qquad n \gg 1
> $$

Then,
$$\color{#00f}{\large%
\lim_{n \to \infty}\bracks{%
\pars{2 \over 1}^{2}\pars{4 \over 3}^{2}
     \pars{6 \over 5}^{2}\ldots \pars{2n \over 2n - 1}^{2}{1 \over 2n + 1}}
= {\pi \over 2}}
$$